# If email HTML image can't be downloaded, img placeholder is really large

Tags: html, css, html-email

I have the following html:

```
...
<td>
   <img src="/img/myimage.jpg"/>
</td>
...
```

Styled:

```
img {
  height:auto;
  width:600px;
}
```

The image is for a banner that I have on the top of HTML emails. I need it to always resize to a width of 600px, and then scale the height relative to the width (so the image doesn't distort).

This works fine if the image is successfully loaded, but if the image 404s the placeholder that remains is 600px by 600px. This makes sense, but it looks awful!

I can't work out the best way to limit the resizing of the height if no image can be downloaded. I can't set a max-height or height as this will distort the image if it is successfully downloaded (note the image files height can be variable).

Any ideas?

Comment: Why can't you set a height? If it's the correct height of the image it wouldn't be distorted.

Comment: @WesleyMurch the question is about what to do when there is no image; that is, when the image load fails.

Comment: What about including another img tag with the placeholder above your to-be downloaded image? Some relative positioning with z-indexing would make it such that a successfully downloaded image would appear over the placeholder.

Comment: @Pointy: Set the height to the file's height. The "placeholder" should take the same size as the actual image. (also good to prevent reflow when the image downloads)

Comment: @WesleyMurch ... there is no file ... really I doubt there's much to be done; it's part of the evil of HTML email.

Comment: The height of the image can vary, otherwise you are right, i could set a height.

Comment: I can't think of a way to solve this, without using javascript. I do not believe there is a way to check wether an image loads or not, using only HTML and CSS.

Comment: yeah js can be used, but not supported in lots if email clients http://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/better-broken-image-handling/

Comment: @Gaz_Edge You should still be able to set a height, just as long as it's correct for the particular image you're embedding. At the least, you could use a sensible `max-height` that would cover all scenarios.

Comment: @WesleyMurch good thinking. I do roughly know the image height will be less than 400px. That will be slightly better. Add that as an answer

Comment: @Gaz_Edge, I wasn't trying to troll... If you must know, what you ask exactly is not do-able in pure HTML/CSS. Trying to know more details on the way you are composing and sending the mail could greatly help in finding alternatives to achieve what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The actual answer to this question is its not possible in pure HTML/CSS. Email clients have poor support for JS so that's not an option.

Since the height of the image could be anything, and checking the link every time seems unnecessary for such a minor issue, the solution for me is to accept the limitations of HTML emails and accept that the missing image will be an odd size.

Answer (score 0):

Considering that you are sending an HTML mail using server side programming:

1. Check if the image file exists
2. Insert the file's content in base64 encoding directly in the src (that way never 404s)

If you really do not want to send the picture inline in the mail:

1. Check if image file exists (using URL)
2. Fetch the image sizes and write them in the img tag

Comment: I know the file exists, but the nature of the html emails means that some clients may not be able to download it (maybe they have outlook and image downloads are not allowed).

Comment: If the file exists, when composing the e-mail, you could define the height at that time. Or add the file directly in the mail like a lot of advertisers do. Isn't that a viable option? When sending a mail through thunderbird, the picture you add are directly inserted in the e-mail, not placed on a cdn so everyone is sure to receive your image.

Answer (score 0):

Try to place your image in div tag and set it style min-height:200px for example or limple add min-height parameter to image if it is possible.

Comment: Set the minimum height of element. probably i cant check it. it just sets MINIMUM size of container.